# How to download and install an updated Certificate Revocation List?

Tags: windows-7, certificate, code-signing

I don't want that my Windows 7 machine download CRLs at boot time. Can I do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the [Certificate Manager Tool (Certmgr.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This thread seems to answer your question.
Look at the last post, according to the poster it is impossible to dissable this from the client-side.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserversecurity/thread/f91beabe-9143-4908-8469-664feaeec3d9

On the other hand, if you want to disable it from the server, you can then do it by hand:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680540.aspx

Good luck!